# Append data to hdf5 container with Matlab

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I created a HDF5 container using MATLAB. Content are several images with dimensions `[1024 1024 4]` (= width, height, channels). I created and filled the dataset like this:

```
% GENERATE DATA
img = double(ones([1024 1024 4]));             % example for image
imgs_dset = double(ones([size(img) n_imgs]);   % dataset [1024 1024 4 n_imgs]
datasetname = '/data';

% CREATE hdf5 container
% dset_size is 'Inf' so that container can hold arbitrary number of imgs
dset_size = [size(img) Inf];                   % = [1024 1024 4 Inf]
h5create(filename, datasetname, dset_size, 'Datatype', class(imgs_dset));

% FILL dataset
h5write(filename, datasetname, imgs_dset);
```

That is all good, all `n_imgs` are written to the file. However I now want to add further images into the same dataset, **not knowing the size  `n_imgs` of the created file** (the appending script accesses the file independently from the creation script).

For older versions there was an option like `'WriteMode', 'append'`, but now the function h5write expects the parameters `start` and `count` ([doc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5write.html) is here).

I'm puzzled on how to determine these parameters. In the example they set

```
start = [1 j];  % probably translates to [1 n_imgs]?
count = [20 1]; % translates to [img ?]
```

How would I set these parameters in my example?

1. If I know `n_imgs`?
2. If I don't know `n_imgs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start` is where in the data you are going to start writing to the file. `count` is how much data you will write to the file.

Assuming `n_imgs` have already been written to the file and you wish to append, `start` would be `[1 1 1 n_imgs+1]`. (i.e. start writing to the file at the beginning of where the next image will be). Say you wish to append 5 new images to the file, `count` will be `[1024 1024 4 5]`.

If you don't know how many images have been written to the hdf5 previously, you can look it up using `h5info`

Here's your example and how you could append to it:

```
% GENERATE DATA
n_imgs = 3;
img = double(ones([1024 1024 4]));             % example for image
imgs_dset = double(ones([size(img) n_imgs]));   % dataset [1024 1024 4 n_imgs]
datasetname = '/data';
filename = 'data.h5';

% CREATE hdf5 container
% dset_size is 'Inf' so that container can hold arbitrary number of imgs
dset_size = [size(img) Inf];                   % = [1024 1024 4 Inf]
h5create(filename, datasetname, dset_size, ...
         'Datatype', class(imgs_dset), 'ChunkSize', [1024 1024 1 1] );

% FILL dataset with first few images
h5write(filename, datasetname, imgs_dset, [1 1 1 1], [size(img) n_imgs]);

% APPEND to dataset
n_new_images = 5;
new_imgs_dset = double(ones([size(img) n_new_images]));
info = h5info('data.h5', '/data');
curSize = info.Dataspace.Size; % is currently [1024 1024 4 3].
h5write(filename, datasetname, new_imgs_dset, ...
             [1 1 1 curSize(end)+1], [size(img) n_new_images]);

% check size of dataset after appending:
info = h5info('data.h5', '/data');
disp(info.Dataspace.Size) % size is now [1024 1024 4 8]
```

Comment: great, that is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the explanation!